# How to search for a URL occurrences in Google search results?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I am interested in finding out count of Google search results containing a full URL path. I know we do search for a fully qualified domain or sub-domain. However, have not been able to find a way to search for a path or document.

*For example: I want to know how many Google search results contain "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.konsier.konsier_infocard"*.

Answer (score 11):

`inurl:play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.konsier.konsier_infocard`

[Source](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html)

Comment: Wow! I've needed something like this forever. Thanks a ton!